# Figuring out the difference in days between events

Tags: php, datetime

I have a MySQL DB with StartDates in the format of yyyy-mm-dd and starttimes in the format of HH:MM using a 24 hour clock.  What would be the easiest way to compare the difference of two days in PHP?  Would using a datetime object could I set it to be with the information given and just give it to zeros for the seconds?  I need to get the amount of time between both dates down to the minute.  I was putting the startdate (Just the day since its always within the same month for my application) and time together concatenated together and then pulling out what I need like below, but I haven't been able to get it straight yet.  Thanks for the look!

```
$tempvar1 = $times[$i][$j];
$tempvar2 = $times[$i][$j+1];
$day1 = $tempvar1[0].$tempvar1[1];
$day2 = $tempvar2[0].$tempvar2[1];
$hours1 = $tempvar1[2].$tempvar1[3];
$hours2 = $tempvar2[2].$tempvar2[3];
$minutes1 = $tempvar1[5].$tempvar1[6];
$minutes2 = $tempvar2[5].$tempvar2[6];
$numdays = ($day2-$day1) - 1;
$time1 = ($hours1*60)+$minutes1;
$time2 = ($hours2*60)+$minutes2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has plenty of date/time functions:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(endtime, starttime), DATEDIFF(endtime, starttime)
FROM ...
```

doc links for [timediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

That'll you get strings in the format of 'hh:mm:ss.ssss' for timediff, and a straight-up integer representing the days between the two dates, respectively.